# Is it possible to build a generic function for the fetches?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I build an app in react.js with a lot of 'crud' operations. I am a beginner in React. For all these fetches there are always the same header (content-type, token...). And for each requests I have to resolve promises, test the code status, parse the answer, manage the errors , etc.... It is very long to write.

So I wonder if is possible to build a generic function. Something like that:

```
myBooks = callApi('endpoint', 'myparams');
```

And that's all ! The function callApi would do all the necessary (add the headers, the token, etc....).

I tried on my side, but I have not enough skills to do that in React.

Do you make your fetches with a special package ? or do you write, like me, your fetches and too bad it's long to write.

Do you have some packages to suggest?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fetch-wrapper

Comment: but my personal suggestion is Axios

Comment: Is this a React question, or a more general JavaScript question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `axios` for fetching from REST APIs. You can use `axios.create` to create an instance that you can pass headers and the base url of your API. You could even define middlewares with axios.

Using [axios create](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Personally, I prefer to just wrap my axios calls myself like this:

```
function getHeaders() {
    return {
        accept: 'application/json',
        authorization: `Bearer ${ getStoredAuthToken() }`,
    };
}

function postHeaders() {
    return {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        authorization: `Bearer ${ getStoredAuthToken() }`,
    };
}

export const postRequest = ( endpoint, data ) => axios
    .post( API + endpoint, data, { headers: postHeaders() } )
    .then( res => res.data )
    .catch( ( err ) => {
        LoggingUtility.error( `Error in post request to endpoint ${ endpoint }`, err );
        if ( isNetworkError( err ) ) {
            throwServerNotReachableError();
        }
        const { status } = err.response;
        if ( isUnauthorizedError( status ) ) {
            return refreshAuthToken(
                () => postRequest( endpoint, data ),
            );
        }
        throw err;
    } );
```

You could do something like this for every http method, e.g. deleteRequest, putRequest, postRequest etc.

In React/Frontend land it is very common to do this in a folder called `services` which abstracts away all async fetches of data.

Comment: Thanks Andre for the answer. I understand that it is a good practice to build these fetches outside the component. I will inspired by your code.

Comment: I imagine that the const API is the endpoint (eg : http://myendpoint/) . As it does not change, I guess I can write like const API = 'http://myendpoint'. Correct ?

Comment: Exactly! I have a constant called `const API = process.env.host` which points either to my local or my production backend based on environment variables :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes totally. You can create a callApi function like this:

```
const callApi = (url, params) => {
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  let heads = {};
  let body = params;

  if (token !== null && token !== undefined && token !== ''){
    heads['token'] = token;
  }

  heads["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  body = params && JSON.stringify(params);

  let options = {
    mode: "cors",
    method: "POST",
    headers: heads
  };

  if (body) options['body'] = body;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const res = await response.json();
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Harshit. Yes with your response and the response of Andre, I must be able to build something. Thanks !

Comment: @Dom Glad to help. Do upvote if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

I have actually done this on personal projects before, here is the basics that I use.

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
const port = '8080';

export async function get(route) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}:${port}/${route}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    });
    return response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`GET error: ${err}`);
  }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to modify this for authentication, https, etc, but you'll call it with something like (for a similar post method) (and one for get):

```
const response = await post('user-files/update', {
  uuid,
  newFilename: filename,
  originalFilename,
});

const rows = await get(`dataset/${uuid}`);
```

Comment: Thanks Sterling for you answer. May I ask you to read this post please ? It is a try I made for this generic function. Is it , for you, a good code ? Many thanks. Dom .       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341078/generic-function-to-request-api-with-axios